# Trying to use input from prompt as object value within a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, object

Please be aware that I have only learned how to use objects this morning, so this is mainly an exercise to play around with this.

I was able to set up an array with a list of students. Each student is an object with multiple properties. I was also able to add another property and value to each object within the array using a for loop.

What I'm trying to do now is prompt the user to enter an object name "student1, student2, etc." I'm trying to use the value of that prompt, saved as var studentSelected, in the function reportStudentInfo(info).

What does work: If i get rid of the variable "selectedStudent", and I specifically decide to put in an object value student1, student2, etc. it works as expected.

What I don't understand:
I'm guessing the value of the prompt changes to a string from the prompt and it seems to mess up the value of what the object is, even though the prompt input might be: "student1" the function isn't reading it as student1. It returns an undefined value for each of the object property values.

I really hope I asked a clear enough question. Thanks for any help.

- Logan

link to JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/lwood3499/aevsbrk8/

```
var selectedStudent = prompt("Which student do you want to see the results for Test #1?");
```

reportStudentInfo( selectedStudent.name + " : " + selectedStudent.test1 );

Comment: You need to use selectedStudent to select the desired entry from the list. I updated your JSFiddle so it works: https://jsfiddle.net/aevsbrk8/1/

Comment: Sorry, but it does not seem to provide any output. It still prompts just like before. But not even the "undefined : undefined" appears like earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After

```
var selectedStudent = prompt("Which student do you want to see the results for Test #1?");
```

`selectedStudent` is a string entered at the prompt. It does not have `name` or `test1` properties.

If `selectedStudent` object already exists, you can do

```
var selectedStudent.name = prompt("Which student do you want to see the results for Test #1?");
```

or

```
var studentName = prompt("Which student do you want to see the results for Test #1?");
```

Update:

```
var selectedStudent = prompt("Which student do you want to see the results for Test #1?");
var found = null;
for (var iter = 0; iter < list.length; iter++) {
  if (selectedStudent == list[iter].name) {
    found = list[iter];
    break;
  }
}
if (found) {
  reportStudentInfo(found.name + " : " + found.test1 );
} else {
  alert(selectedStudent + " not found");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for confirming that the prompt returns a string that is not the same as the object name. I assumed, but wasn't sure. I had a link to the JSFiddle that hopefully helps clarify what I am trying. I tried the selectedStudent.name approach within the function. It just doesn't seem to carry the same value. When I manually type in the same characters that a user might put in the prompt, it works. I guess the question is: Is there a way to convert the prompt string back into the object value? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Igor - it appears to only return student not found.

Comment: @LoganWood - appears? No, it works correctly, as long as you type the correct name. https://jsfiddle.net/aevsbrk8/2/

Comment: Wow, thank you. I was still typing "student1" as the object name trying to do a search like I had originally set it up, but the way you set it up is much better being able to type in their actual name. Thanks! Now I just need to break it down and figure out why it works.  lol I'm still very new at this, so thanks for your patience. Also, since you didn't answer, but replied with a comment...how do I give you points or like your advice? Thanks again!

Comment: @LoganWood - "since you didn't answer, but replied with a comment"??? Look above this comment.